# Array of structs containing functions as members C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I need an array of structs that is going to be used to draw the elements of the screen based on what is the selected point (which is just a number).

Mainly I'm interested in the correct syntax of declaring a struct that has function pointers as members, creating an array that has elements of that struct type and passing arguments to those functions. Something like the code below but with correct syntax.

```
struct menuStruct 
{
   void *leftEdgeSymbol(boolean show);
   void *certerScreenSymbol(boolean show);
   void *rightEdgeSymbol(boolean show);
   void *buttonFunction(void);
}; 


menuStruct allMenues[] = 
{
  {drawLeftArrow(), drawTempSettingText(), drawRightArrow(), mainMenu1()},  //0
  {eraseLeftArrow(), drawHumidTargetText(), drawRightArrow(), mainMenu2()},  //1
  {drawLeftMinusSign(), drawSetTempTarget(), drawRightPlusSign(), subMenu101()  //2
}




void drawLeftArrow(boolean show)
{
 //Draw the arrow with white colour to show or with black to erase 
}

void rightArrow(boolean show)
{
 //Draw the arrow with white colour to show or with black to erase 
}
```

Comment: why does `menuStruct` have function pointers as members instead declaring methods that are overriden by subclasses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: plus you have `std::function` in `c++`

Comment: Why are you using a C-ism erzatz of OOP in C++?

Comment: @user463035818 There are two clear benefits to not doing the inheritance dance: you can define a new menu without the hassle of defining Yet Another Subclass with overrides that mostly do nothing except forward to another function, and the whole system is defined in one single place instead of spread out over all those subclasses.

Comment: @molbdnilo sure, i am not a big fan of using inheritance for everything either, was just trying to find out what was OPs motivation to enter the hassle of using function pointers when inheritance would do as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax would be

```
struct menuStruct 
{
   void (*leftEdgeSymbol)(bool);
   void (*certerScreenSymbol)(bool);
   void (*rightEdgeSymbol)(bool);
   void (*buttonFunction)();
}; 

void drawLeftArrow(bool show)
{
     //Draw the arrow with white colour to show or with black to erase 
}

void rightArrow(bool show);

// ...

menuStruct allMenues[] = 
{
  {&drawLeftArrow, &drawTempSettingText, &drawRightArrow, &mainMenu1},  //0
  {&eraseLeftArrow, &drawHumidTargetText, &drawRightArrow, &mainMenu2},  //1
  {&drawLeftMinusSign, &drawSetTempTarget, &drawRightPlusSign, &subMenu101}  //2
}
```

and possible usage:

```
allMenues[1].rightEdgeSymbol(false);
```

Comment: It compiles thank you so much.
How do i call and pass arguements to those funcrions? 

    allMenues[2](*leftEdgeSymbol)(TRUE);

Comment: @vangde: Usage added.